# Printing output of shell script running inside a docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile in which I have specified an ENTRYPOINT "my_script.sh".In my_script.sh,I am exe.cuting a CURL command.When the docker image with this Dockerfile is built.How should I run it so that output of my_script.sh will be printed on my host.

Dockerfile -

```
FROM my-company-repo-java-base-image
ADD my_script.sh /root
ENTRYPOINT bash "/root/my_script.sh
```

my_script.sh

```
echo "Hello My Script"
curl -x POST "some_api_which_returns_json"
```

I have built the image using command
docker build

I want to run this image and see output of my_script.sh on my dockerhost.

Comment: What have you tried already?  What doesn’t work?  Why does Docker need to be involved?

Answer (score 4):

Given a Docker image whose tag is $DOCKER_IMAGE:

```
docker container run -it --rm $DOCKER_IMAGE
```

`-i` keeps STDIN open
`-t` allocates a pseudo-TTY
`--rm` automatically removes the container when it exits

See [docker container run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_run/) for all the options.

Comment: After adding this,I am getting "not a TTY device" error from my jenkins job

Comment: Ah, in the context of a CI job, you likely don't want the the container to be run interactively with a pseudo-TTY. In that case, simply drop those two arguments. docker container run --rm $DOCKER_IMAGE

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can see the output of shell script. Make sure you delete the old image before building new one when you change the script. Else, your container will keep using the old script over and over. Here's an example

- Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.7

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/myscript.sh"]

COPY myscript.sh /usr/bin/myscript.sh
```

- myscript.sh

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo "Hello there"
```

- commands to run:

```
docker image rm testdocker
docker build --tag testdocker .
docker run testdocker
```

You should see the line `Hello there` appears on the terminal